# Could we detect gravitational waves emitted outside particle horizon?

Tags: gravitational-waves, event-horizon, observable-universe

As we can see from a normal spacetime diagram like below, there's an overlap of the area within the event horizon and the area outside the particle horizon. Could we detect gravitational waves from this part which is part of the "unobservable universe"?

Since light cannot travel through the early universe due to the particle density, we cannot detect electromagnetic waves from beyond. This doesn't seem to be the case for gravitational waves. But obviously I'm not smarter than the scientists, so what have I got wrong?

If gravitational waves did emit from beyond the observable universe, where could they be from? Are the objects/events emitting these gravitational waves not created by our Big Bang?

This is my first question, thank you for reading and replying.

[image: graph]

[image: graph]

[image: graph]

Comment: we can barely detect gravitational waves from black holes systems spinning at thousands of RPM, and you want to detect the echoes from the formation of the universe???